Bug in survey_questions collection in Firebase Firestore
I'm facing an issue where I'm trying to query the survey_questions collection in Firestore using python, but the query returns an empty result (List of documents: []), even though the collection is populated with documents (confirmed by the Firebase Console).
Here's a summary of the issue:
I can successfully query the users collection, but not survey_questions.
The survey_questions Firestore collection exists and contains documents, as verified in the Firebase Console.
No errors are being thrown; the query itself completes, but returns no documents.
The collection name is spelled correctly and I'm using the same Firestore client configuration for both collections.
The issue persists despite logging the query object, which shows no signs of a problem, and running the stream method on the collection returns an empty list.
Here is the code:
from app.configs.firebase_config import db

class SurveyRepository:
    def __init__(self):
        self.survey_questions_collection = db.collection('survey_questions')
        
        
    def get_survey_questions(self):
        try:
            query = self.survey_questions_collection
            docs = query.stream()

            print('query', query)
            print('docs', docs)

            docs_list = []
            for doc in docs:
                if doc:
                    print('Document ID:', doc.id)
                    print('Document Data:', doc.to_dict())
                    docs_list.append(doc.to_dict())
                else:
                    print('No document found.')

            print("Documents List:", docs_list)
            return docs_list

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


Please edit the question to show the proof you have that documents exist.  Since you said you're using the Firebase console, a screenshot of that would be helpful.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.
